# AWS Static website hosting redirects not working on Apple products?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

We have a setup of a DNS registered in Route53 (on a separate AWS account) pointing to a CloudFront which in turn has an S3 bucket setup as Static website hosting with a redirect.
The redirect is a path, like `otherdomain.com/#!/code?lang=fi` while the DNS is `signup.domain.com`.

This *works perfectly on most laptops, all Windows and Android devices* but **fails on iPhones, iPads and some MAC with Safari**.
On the Apple devices the user is redirected to `otherdomain.com/` (without any path) so there is a redirect happening but the path is lost somewhere along the way...

What is happening here?

Comment: Note that this isn't the *path* thar you are losing, it's the *fragment*, which is potentially a very different issue.   Your path is `/`, the fragment delimiter is `#` and the rest of the fragment is `!/code?lang=fi`.  Can you give us the real URL?

Comment: Ok, thanks for setting me straight! :) The url's are signup.qvalia.fi which should forward you to https://qvaliainvoices.com/#!/code?lang=fi